# Increasing open files limit for all processes: Do I need to set Soft/Hard limits?

Tags: linux, centos, limit, ulimit, resources

I'm trying to fix the following error that I get after a day or two of running my game server.

```
2017/12/13 12:08:35 http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8081: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s
```

I added "fs.file-max = 2000000" to /etc/sysctl.conf and executed

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=2000000
sysctl -p
```

My global limits are now updated (do I need to reboot?) but the soft and hard limits are still 1024 and 4096 respectively.

Also when using the following command to check for "open files" for root user:

```
su - root -c 'ulimit -aHS' -s '/bin/bash'
```

I'm getting 1024 as well.

What does the soft and hard limit do and do I need to change them in order for the global limits to have any effect? And how about the user (root) limit?

Thanks!

Comment: the error you get "after a day or two"... Does the problem appear when there's a large number of simultaneous users, or at arbitrary times after the server has been running sufficiently long? I.e. do we know it's not just opening files all the time, but neglecting to close them?

Comment: Yes it mostly happens when it's been populated for a while.

Comment: @ilkkachu It mostly happens after 2 busy evenings, where people have been leaving and joining frequently.

Answer (score 4):

The limit you set with `sysctl` is a system setting that applies to the whole system. It is not a limit that applies to individual processes.

Each process can have no more than N files open where N is the process's `NOFILE` soft limit, and it can change its own soft limit to no more than the hard limit. Only processes running as root can raise their hard limit. Processes inherit their parent's limits.

The way to change the limit for a single service (which is what you should do) depends on your init system.

- For SysVinit (CentOS ≤6): edit the init script for the service (normally located in `/etc/rc.d/init.d`) to call `ulimit` before running the daemon, then restart the service.
- For Systemd (CentOS ≥7): edit the [service's unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LimitCPU=) `/etc/systemd/system/my_game_server.service` and add a directive

  ```
  LimitNOFILE=16384
  ```

  Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the configuration, then restart your service.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running my program in a screen on root user, CentOS7. Does that mean I don't have to change anything now?

Comment: @SJ19 You do need to change the service's unit file, unless you've changed the limits globally as in Romeo's answer.

Comment: @Gilles, If I've understood correctly, `limits.conf` is the configuration file of `pam_limits.so`. Does it apply to daemons started by init in any system (or any init, for that matter)? Though if SJ19 starts their daemon from an interactive session, then the limits of the session would be the ones that matter...

Comment: @ilkkachu It doesn't apply to daemons started by init at boot time. But under SysVinit it would indirectly apply to a daemon started by someone typing `start-stop-daemon …` or `/etc/rc.d/…` in a shell.

Comment: @ilkkachu What exactly does "pam" and "daemon" mean? And why would I need to change those rather than the user limits? It just keeps getting more confusing to me... I appreciate the help though!

Comment: @SJ19 The limits in `limits.conf` apply when a user logs in. They don't apply for system services that are started automatically at boot time. For this, on CentOS 7, edit the service's unit file. Although if your service runs as root (which is a bad idea, it makes it a lot worse the day your server gets hacked) you can add an `ulimit` command to the script that launches it.

Comment: @Gilles I manually run the program after a restart (on root), so all of this doesn't really apply to me right?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Log out and in to take effect.

Hardlimit: The boundary for a certain user - can not be increaed by that user during runtime, only decreased: `ulimit -Hu 2000`. List of Hardlimits: `ulimit -Ha`

Softlimit: A "soft" boundary within the hardlimit, can be changed by the user during runtime: `ulimit -Su 10000`.List of Softlimits: `ulimit -Sa`

Change ulimits for a running process: `prlimit -p $$ --nproc=1200:`. This will change the number of processes (softlimit) to 1200 for the current shell `$$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of limits in file `/etc/security/limits.conf` (for particular user or for everyone)
You should add like this:

```
username               soft    nofile          4096
username               hard    nofile          5120
```

and this will set number of open files to 4096 (soft limit) and 5120 as top

After this edit you need to relogin and restrart the service(s) to get this in charge.

As far as I remember `ulimit` will make changes only till you logout from this user

Comment: Thanks, does that mean that the change that I did so far has no effect until I change the soft and hard limit too? And how would you set the limits for everyone and not just a specific username?

Comment: I am afraid so, as far as I know `sysctl` will change the parameter in kernel, but if you have limit in `limits.conf` they will limit you

Comment: CentOS7 may or may not also need corresponding entries in the systemd service file. (`LimitFiles` if I remember correctly.)

Comment: I should mention that I'm running my program in a screen on root user, does that make a difference?

Comment: @SJ19, I do not think so. Change the limits for `root` user, logout, login again and run it

Comment: @RomeoNinov Does the soft limit even matter when you're the root user? I might've misunderstood this, but I believe someone else said that the soft limit gets increased automatically when it's reached? And is there anything wrong with just setting both the soft and hard limit to like 2 million? Like what's the point of the soft limit.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Rebooting is also okay right? Instead of logging out and in.

Comment: @SJ19, correct. But this is very "heavy" way to do this :)